# Many-To-Many Relationships: Lazy Loading in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many, lazy-loading

I have two entities:

- ARTICLE

  - barcode
  - description
  - price

==========

- CATEGORY

  - id
  - description

This entities has a many-to-many relationships. How can I implement lazy-loading to avoid memory issue? I have 300.000+ articles.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data does all the lazy loading for you. Relationship is a fault by default. It’s only when you try to traverse it does the fault fire and the real data will be read from the store into the memory.